# Jump/Throw Coding or Animation Issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, unity3d-2dtools

## The Setup

I have a basketball player with an animator and 5 assigned animations to that animator as followed:

1. PlayerIdle
2. PlayerWalk
3. PlayerJump
4. PlayerBend
5. PlayerShoot

[Setup_FruitHoops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lzPE.png)

[Player Animation Window with Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah6Vf.png)

## The Problem

In PlayMode, the player is able to move and jump successfully. The issue comes when the player attempts to grab the apple that is on the ground. The desired game design that I wanted was for the player to bend over and grab the apple by pressing the G key and then press G again to throw the apple towards the hoop to score a point. However, when I run it and after I first press G, the player can no longer jump, grab, or throw. The below section is the code for PlayerMovement and GrabberScript. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

## PlayerMovement.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator anim;
    private bool isGrounded, jumped;
    private float jumpshotPower = 6f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GameObject.Find("Player Parent").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GameObject.Find("Player Parent").GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        CheckIfGrounded();
        PlayerJump();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        PlayerWalk();
    }

    void PlayerWalk()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (h > 0)
        {
            //going right
            anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
            ChangeDirection(-1);
        }
        else if (h < 0)
        {
            //going left
            anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);
            ChangeDirection(1);
        }
        else
        {
            //standing still
            anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }

    void ChangeDirection(int d)
    {
        Vector3 temp = transform.localScale;
        temp.x = d;
        transform.localScale = temp;
    }

    void CheckIfGrounded()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.Raycast(groundCheck.position, Vector2.down, 0.1f, groundLayer);
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (jumped)
            {
                jumped = false;
                anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            }
        }
    }
    void PlayerJump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                jumped = true;
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpshotPower);
                anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## GrabberScript.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GrabberScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool grabbed, throwObject;
    private RaycastHit2D hit;
    public float distance;
    public Transform holdpoint;
    public float throwForce;
    public LayerMask notFruitLayer;
    private Animator anim;

    private void Awake()
    {
        anim = GameObject.Find("Player Parent").GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            if (!grabbed)
            {
                //grab fruit
                anim.Play("PlayerBend");
                Physics2D.queriesStartInColliders = false;
                hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down * transform.localScale.x, distance);

                if(hit.collider != null && hit.collider.tag == "Apple")
                {
                    grabbed = true;
                }
            }
            else if(!Physics2D.OverlapPoint(holdpoint.position, notFruitLayer))
            {
                //throw fruit
                grabbed = false;

                if(hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() != null)
                {
                    PlayerShooting();
                }
            }

            if (grabbed)
            {
                hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position = holdpoint.position;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + Vector3.down * transform.localScale.x * distance);
    }

    void PlayerShooting()
    {
        if (grabbed == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.G))
            {
                throwObject = true;
                hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, 1) * throwForce;
                anim.Play("PlayerShoot");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your animator states? I think there is no way to back from "PlayerBend" state in animator. in your code for walking you are changing "isWalking" boolean but it will works if you be in correct state. so my advice is start the game and check animator states carefully.

Comment: _Just edited it. Picture of player animations are now attached._

Comment: ok, there is no transition from "playerBend" or "playershot" to other states, so when you play these two animations, animator will stay there and set boolean ("isWalking") for that states has no effects. add transitions and states to your animator. for example you can add transition from "playerBent" to "Idle" state.

Comment: Ok. I understand that and just added transitions from “Bent” to “Idle” and vice versa. Did the same thing on PlayerShoot to idle. It fixed the part of the problem with animator states getting stuck. However, the player is still not grabbing the apple or jumping/shooting after he goes to grab the apple that first time. I’m suspecting that it has to do with the player movement script or the raycast code in the GrabberScript.